# Deleting an element and child nodes in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Before I get downvoted, I have seen many posts relating to this exact topic. I have attempted

```
  public int deleteMsg(string senderID)
  {
    XDocument xmlDocMsgs = XDocument.Load(XMLLocale);
    XNamespace nameSpace = "http://example.com/Messages";
    XElement queryElementItems =
         xmlDocMsgs.Descendants(nameSpace+"Message").Where(a => a.Element(nameSpace+"senderID").Value == senderID).FirstOrDefault();
    queryElementItems.Remove();
    xmlDocMsgs.Save(XMLLocale);
  }
    //still need to figure out count of how many messages deleted
```

and Linq

```
    public int deleteMsg(string senderID)
    {
        int count = 0;
        XDocument xmlDocMsgs = XDocument.Load(XMLLocale);
        XNamespace nameSpace = "http://example.com/Messages";
        IEnumerable<XElement> queryElementItems =
            from item in xmlDocMsgs.Root.Descendants(nameSpace + "Message")
            where item.Element(nameSpace + "senderID").Value == senderID
            orderby (DateTime)item.Element(nameSpace + "TS") descending
            select item;
        foreach(XElement item in queryElementItems)
        {
            item.Remove();
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

my XML sheet

```
<Messages xmlns="http://example.com/Messages">
  <Message>
    <SenderID>test</SenderID>
    <ReceiverID>test</ReceiverID>
    <TS>3/11/2018 6:36:33 PM</TS>
    <MessageContents>test</MessageContents>
  </Message>
</Messages>
```

I am trying to create a simple messaging service in visual studio.
I understand how to add data into an xml file, but I am wanting to remove all messages from a specific senderID. So if senderID.value is the same as the parameter, I want to delete the  message node and all child nodes. I read in a few posts that you cannot just remove elements that they have to be in a list. and so i also tried implementing

```
var nodesToBeDeleted = queryElementItems.ToList();
```

and then tried doing my foreach. Everytime i test my service I am getting a 400 error. I am running out of ideas on how to implement this method.

Comment: Test your code in isolation. What's with the http?

Comment: @AluanHaddad My professor always implemented nameSpaces in his xml's when working on a web service so its kinda a habit, but im still learning about xml in general. is it not needed? Thank you

Comment: what does that have to do with HTTP errors? Why don't you test your code outside of the context of a web service call? I personally wouldn't use a namespace but I also wouldn't use XML for a web service

Comment: I'd have a model that the xml gets deserialized to, then remove the messages from that model and serialize ... is there a reason you are messing around with xml directly? Did you check your resulting xml? Is it still valid? Are the `queryElementItems` you get actually those you expect to be removing?

Comment: @Fildor I know I should probably use a proper DB, but for small project i wanted to complete it in XML. so for linq implementation i am able to get the correct elements. but the thing is i cant just simply delete them for some reason.. (previous posts indicated it needed to be in a list which ive tried..)

Comment: Depends. They do not have to live in a "messages" context (tag) to be deserialized as list - but that's totally ok and serves readability. I don't see why you shouldn't be able to delete any Element from that XML so long it still results in valid xml. Can you add an example of before / after deletion xml ?

Comment: @Fildor I did a debug, it looks like when i searched through senderID, i kept getting a nullexception. I took off nameSpace, and it didnt give me an error, but it was not deleting anything. I looked through my xml file and it was SenderID (capital S). was supposed to capitalize it. so i did nameSpace+"SenderID" and it finally worked and deleted the correct message!

Comment: :D Yeah, debugging is king ...